# How to add at the end of a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to make a function that adds at the end of a linked list but I get a segmentation fault.
I don't really know what's wrong with my code. I first check if the list is empty. If it is not empty then I first find the end of the list using `n` I use a while loop to do this, then once that loop is done I then set `n->next = tmp;`

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

typedef Node Node;

void add(Node* &head, int data) {

    Node *tmp = new Node;
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (!head) {
        head->next = tmp;
    } else {
        Node *n = head;
        while (n->next) {
            n= n->next;
        }
        n->next = tmp;
    }
}

int main() {
    Node *head = NULL;

    add(head,1);
    add(head,2);

    Node *tmp = head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        cout << tmp->data;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: You check `if (!head)` and then, if `head` ***is*** null, you immediately proceed to dereference it with `head->next = tmp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `head` is `NULL`, you are doing:

```
if (!head) {
    head->next = tmp;
}
```

but there is no `next` for a `NULL` pointer, so this invokes undefined behavior.

You should instead do:

```
if (!head) {
    head = tmp;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/JiJk5Z).

Also, avoid the `NULL` macro, and use `nullptr` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
head->next = tmp;
```

does not work since `head` is a `nullptr` when you enter that branch of code. It needs to be

```
head = tmp;
```

---

As a coding guideline,

1. You don't need `struct Node* next`. It can be just `Node* next`.
2. You don't need `typedef Node Node`.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

// No need of this
// typedef Node Node;
```